# How to render default values from Django Serializer for charting purposes?

Tags: django-rest-framework, chart.js

I'm using Django Rest to aggregate some data for my front end to render (through Chart.js)

Say I want to have a chart with the months (Jan-Dec) on the x-axis and `total_cost` values on the y-axis. How can I make sure to always spit out all 12 months and provide "0" for the y-axis if no value for that month is found?

E.g, this serialized data from Django rest is missing values for November and December, but I still need those labels for Chart JS to properly render

```
[
    {
        "month": "2020-01-01",
        "total_cost": "199.00"
    },
    {
        "month": "2020-02-01",
        "total_cost": "222.00"
    },
    {
        "month": "2020-03-01",
        "total_cost": "399.00"
    },
    {
        "month": "2020-04-01",
        "total_cost": "414.00"
    },
    {
        "month": "2020-05-01",
        "total_cost": "555.00"
    },
    {
        "month": "2020-06-01",
        "total_cost": "615.00"
    },
    {
        "month": "2020-07-01",
        "total_cost": "700.00"
    },
    {
        "month": "2020-08-01",
        "total_cost": "913.00"
    },
    {
        "month": "2020-09-01",
        "total_cost": "552.00"
    },
    {
        "month": "2020-10-01",
        "total_cost": "1000.00"
    }
]
```

Perhaps this is a matter for the frontend rather than the backend?

If it helps, my django query looks like this:

```
queryset = Expense.object.annotate(month=TruncMonth('expense_date')) 
           .values('month') 
           .annotate(total_cost=Sum('cost')) 
           .values('month', 'total_cost') 
           .order_by('month')
```

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly guessed, this is best handled in the the frontend rather than in the backend.

You can define your x-axis as a [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html) that accepts the `data` of your dataset as individual [points](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#input-data) through objects containing `x` and `y` properties each. Given the base data present in an array named `baseData`, such data can be created through [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as follows:

```
baseData.map(o => ({ x: o.month, y: Number(o.total_cost) }))
```

To make sure, all 12 months are included in the chart, you'll further have to define `ticks.min` and `ticks.max` options on the x-axis.

```
ticks: {
  min: '2020-01',
  max: '2020-12'
}
```

Please take a look at the following runnable code and see how it works.

> Note that Chart.js internally uses [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for the functionality of the time axis. Therefore you should use the [bundled version](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.

```js
const baseData = [
    { "month": "2020-01-01", "total_cost": "199.00" },
    { "month": "2020-02-01", "total_cost": "222.00" },
    { "month": "2020-03-01", "total_cost": "399.00" },
    { "month": "2020-04-01", "total_cost": "414.00" },
    { "month": "2020-05-01", "total_cost": "555.00" },
    { "month": "2020-06-01", "total_cost": "615.00" },
    { "month": "2020-07-01", "total_cost": "700.00" },
    { "month": "2020-08-01", "total_cost": "913.00" },
    { "month": "2020-09-01", "total_cost": "552.00" },
    { "month": "2020-10-01", "total_cost": "1000.00" }
];

new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'line',  
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: baseData.map(o => ({ x: o.month, y: Number(o.total_cost) })),
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      borderColor: 'green'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'month',
          tooltipFormat: 'MMM YYYY'
        },
        ticks: {
          min: '2020-01',
          max: '2020-12'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 200
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer - how does this work if October and December are mapped, but not November? (What I'm trying to ask is, what if an n-1 month is missing and not only the n'th element(s))?

Comment: @erikvm: If November or any other month in between is missing, this should also work. Just check it by changing the `baseData` in the code sample.

Comment: Just to show what I mean: https://imgur.com/S5BAZSS

I added data for december but not for november, however, when using a line chart, it looks like there is data for november, (the only indication that there is no data is the missing of a node for that month, but at first glance it looks like there is data for november) - shouldnt the line chart "take a dip" for that period instead?

Comment: @erikvm: For such cases, you would normally define the option `spanGaps: false` on the dataset. Unfortunately however this doesn't work when defining the dataset as individual points. Therefore, you could change the `line` chart into a `scatter` chart. If this isn't what you need, a completely different approach for defining the chart `data` is needed.

Comment: @erikvm: Please take a look at the following answer, it may help you finding a solution for the case where data is missing in-between: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63750493/2358409